# How to fix "non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list” <map>

Tags: c++

This works in VS2018, but not in 2008, and i'm not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap = {
        {"Code", "Test"},
        {"Code", "Test1"},
        {"Code", "Test2"},
    };
}
```

This is the error :
`Error  2   error C2552: 'myMap' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list`

Comment: You can't do this in VS2008.  You need a C++11 complaint compiler.

Comment: In 2018 works but not in vs2008... The problem is with the myMap i cannot import them

Comment: This is not a "function"

Comment: What is VS2018, did I miss a version between 2017 and 2019?

Comment: Partial support of C++11 was introduced in `Visual C++ 2010`! `vs2008` is OLDER so do not have C++11 at all.

Comment: @nvoigt MSVC++ 2017 == VS2018 ;)

Comment: The only way to *fix* it in 2008 compiler is by coding a bunch of inserts.

Comment: @DanielLangr Question has been edited since I've posted my comment so it no longer applies here.

Comment: The problem with original code was that it had various normal function calls in global scope, which is not allowed by language, it had nothing to do with actual randomness. I consider any kind of dynamic initialization a poor practice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Use a compiler that supports C++11 or a later version of the standard where extended list initialisation is well-formed. (I.e. give up on VS2008)

Option 2: Write the program in C++03 (or older if necessary) compliant dialect. An example:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Map;
typedef Map::value_type Pair;

Pair elements[] = {
    Pair("Code", "Test"),
    Pair("Code", "Test1"),
    Pair("Code", "Test2"),
};
const std::size_t length = sizeof(elements)/sizeof(*elements);

Map myMap(elements, elements + length);
```

Answer (score 4):

VS2008 is an old compiler that doesn't support C++11 which is needed for this.

You can insert each element:

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap;

    myMap["Code"] = "Test";
    myMap["Code"] = "Test1";
    myMap["Code"] = "Test2";
}
```

Or you can use boost:

```
#include "boost/assign.hpp"

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap = boost::assign::map_list_of
        ("Code", "Test")
        ("Code", "Test1")
        ("Code", "Test2");
}
```

Comment: 'myMap' : 'int []' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>', now i get this error

Comment: @user3682078 double check your code. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you have to make it C++03 compliant (this is what `vs2008` supports), so basically:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap;
    myMap["Code0"] = "Test0";
    myMap["Code1"] = "Test1";
    myMap["Code2"] = "Test2";
}
```

Comment: Now i get this : 'myMap' : 'int []' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>'

Comment: I do not have access to `vs2008`, but it [works here](https://godbolt.org/z/omR5fY). I wonder where this `int []` come from? Do you compile exactly same code?

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Assign](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) can greatly simplify life:

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>

#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    ::std::map< ::std::string, ::std::string > items;
    ::boost::assign::insert(items)
        ("Code", "Test")
        ("Code", "Test1")
        ("Code", "Test2");
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/KcASq3 and `gcc` don't like [`::` after `<` for template parameter](https://godbolt.org/z/AafCmG) space is needed.

Comment: @MarekR damn trigraphs are always getting in the way